# FS rename file - Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '24.png' -> '1.png'

Tags: javascript, fs

I am trying to write a little script that will rewrite the file names of the images in my folder.

Where am I going wrong?

I am getting this error:
FS rename file - Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '24.png' -> '1.png'

```
const fs = require('fs');

const fileNames = fs.readdirSync('./images')

for(const fileName of fileNames) {
    const ext = '.png'
    let incNumber = 1;
    let newName = String(incNumber + ext);
    fs.renameSync(fileName, newName);
    incNumber++
}
```

Comment: What does the toString function do?

Comment: turns the incNumber variable from 1 to 1 but in a string format

Comment: Can you paste it to your question

Comment: Done, I think It can't find the file but im confused as it says 24.png and that's the first image in the folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to change number to string while adding a string into number. If you want to be sure you can call incNumber.toString() + ext

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require("path");
const fileNames = fs.readdirSync('./images')
const ext = '.png'
let incNumber = 1;
for(const fileName of fileNames) {
    let newName = path.join('./images', incNumber + ext);
    fs.renameSync(path.join('./images',fileName), newName);
    incNumber++
}
```

Comment: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '24.png' -> '1.png'
    at Object.renameSync (fs.js:772:3)
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'rename',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '24.png',
  dest: '1.png'
}

Comment: Same error im getting :(

Comment: Do I need to give it the full path?

Comment: fs.renameSync(`/Users/kingy/Desktop/newImages/images/${fileName}`, `/Users/kingy/Desktop/newImages/images/${newName}`) 

Woooo adding the path worked!

Comment: Good! I updated the code. You should also be able to use path!

Answer (score 0):

**If you also need to sort by created date:**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require("path");
const dir = './allHorses';

console.log(dir);

const ext = '.png'
let incNumber = 1;

fs.readdir(dir, function(err, files){
    
    files = files.map(function (fileName) {
      return {
        name: fileName,
        time: fs.statSync(dir + '/' + fileName).mtime.getTime()
      };
    })
    .sort(function (a, b) {
      return a.time - b.time; })
    .map(function (v) {
      return v.name; });

      let files2 = files;

    for(const fileName of files2) {
        let newName = path.join('dir', incNumber + ext);
        fs.renameSync(path.join('dir',fileName), newName);
        incNumber++
    }
});
```